# How to display MudSkeleton, that is replaced by MudImage when the image is actually loaded?

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I can't seem to find a way to use MudSkeleton with MudImage, so the image would show when it's actually loaded.

Currently we are only using an if statement, if there is URI, we show MudImage, otherwise MudSkeleton, but that doesn't work in case of invalid URI.

Example:

```
    @if (ImageUri.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        <MudSkeleton Width="@($"{Width}px")" Height="@($"{Height}px")"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <MudImage Src="@ImageUri" Height="@Height" Width="@Width" ObjectFit="ObjectFit.Contain"/>
    }
```

Comment: Please put some code

Comment: Code sample added.

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid URI" ?

Comment: I mean that the URI would point to a nonexisting image.

Comment: You can create a function that verify if the URI is invalid and call it in the if condition

Comment: Wouldn’t that make 2 calls to retrieve the image?

Comment: The first call should only verify the existence of the image, the second call should retrieve the image and show it's content only if the image exist. If it doesn't, the mudskeleton will be displayed.